Error when app loads navigate before mounting the Root Layout component
I have this structure in my React Native with expo router at my app/_layout.tsx level. Below is my code.   I am trying to fix the issue and error that I am getting when the app loads.  Essentially I am trying to check if use is logged in, if not take them to log in screen or to HomeScreen (app/(tabs)
// app/_layout.tsx
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
  });
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean | null>(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeAuth() {
      const loggedIn = await checkAuthStatus();
      setIsLoggedIn(loggedIn);
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
    initializeAuth();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn === false) {
      router.replace("/(auth)/LoginScreen");
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  if (!loaded || isLoggedIn === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
          <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Slot />
          </Stack>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

authUtils.js
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

// Utility to check if a user token is saved
export async function checkAuthStatus() {
    const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("authToken");
    return !!token;
}

// Utility to save token
export async function setAuthToken(token) {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync("authToken", token);
}

// Utility to clear token
export async function clearAuthToken() {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("authToken");
}


